# '´' came as a complete surprise to me

Tags: c#, antlr4

I'm having trouble setting up ANTLR v4 for C#, anyone keen to help me? I'm using the build target referred from the official site here https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs

I added a simple grammar `Foo.g`

```
grammar Foo;
r  : 'hello' ID ;         // match keyword hello followed by an identifier
ID : [a-z]+ ;             // match lower-case identifiers
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

...and set the build action for it to `Antlr4`

Now I'm stuck with the following errors.

```
'´' came as a complete surprise to me
mismatched input 'grammar' expecting SEMI
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't have enough points to make a comment yet, so this is just a link, but apparently one possible cause of this error message is saving the document in UTF-8 encoding with a BOM.  Apparently this is an issue with the JAVA file input stream.

Notepad++ will let you save without the BOM.

Source: https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/issues/12

Comment: Visual Studio will let you as well, if you use File &rarr; Advanced Save Options...

Comment: Thanks! Now, nothing seems to be generated :( Is antlr v4 even supported on C#?

Comment: This was causing me grief -- I tried saving in 'US-ASCII' format in Visual Studio and it worked.

Comment: If, like me, you do not have the Advanced Save Options in the File menu do the following.  Right-click the File menu and choose Customize.  Switch to the Commands tab and in the top drop down, choose File.  Then press Add Command button.  Finally choose File - Advanced Save Options - OK.  You can optionally move it to where you want it in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue for java target.I saved the grammar file with ANSI encoding in notepad and it started working